# What's this icon in menu bar on Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

Does anyone know what's this icon to the left of battery status in the menu bar? It looks like binoculars.

[image]

This appears only on lock screen, and disappears as soon as I login (either through TouchID or entering the password). Clicking on that while the screen is locked doesn't help.

If it helps, this is a MacBook Pro with TouchBar (2017 model) and is running macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

I've been using this laptop for more than 2 years but this started appearing only 3-4 days ago.

Thanks

Comment: @NimeshNeema Oops! Looks like a duplicate. I'll delete the post then

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) NO need to delete the post. Simply accept the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

if you see it on the lock login screen, it means that your computer is actively creating a video of your screen.

For Reference you can view this article:
https://macreports.com/binoculars-icon-on-mac-what-does-that-mean/